# Make image move position when clicked Elm

Tags: functional-programming, elm

How should I edit my view so that the image stays in a fixed position when I click a certain position. Currently, it follows the mouse.

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model,Cmd.Cmd Msg)
update (MouseMsg pos) model = ({ model | position = {x = pos.x, y = pos.y} },Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html.Html Msg
view model = let
posX = toString model.position.x
posY = toString model.position.y
in
svg [ onClick model ][width "10000",height "10000"] [circle [cx posX, cy posY, r "50", fill "blue" ] []]
```

Comment: Can you give us more detail, particularly in regards to the `subscriptions` function? It sounds like you've probably got subscriptions responding to mouse movement that you need to change to [`Html.Events.onClick`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#onClick)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, easy enough! :)

add a this to your model

```
dragging : Bool
```

add this to your update

```
({ model | dragging = False}, Cmd.none)
```

and add this to your init

```
dragging = True
```